# Python call function for each item in list

Tags: python

I have a set of 3 functions along with a list of names.  I am trying to loop through these names and call a function for each name.  My python looks like this...

```
def testfunc1():
    print("This is a test function 1")
    #print(name)

def testfunc2():
    print("This is a test function 2")
    #print(name)

def testfunc3():
    print("This is a test function 3")
    #print(name)


name_list = ["John", "Joe", "Paul" "George", "Mark", "Craig", "Norman"]
fn_list = [testfunc1(), testfunc2(), testfunc3() ]


for i, name in enumerate(name_list):
    [i % len(fn_list)]()
    print(name)
```

And I would like this to happen...

```
John   - Run testfunc1
Joe    - Run testfunc2
Paul   - Run testfunc3
George - Run testfunc1
Mark   - Run testfunc2
Craig  - Run testfunc3
Norman - Run testfunc1
```

I have several problems with my current code, the first being that currently I get the following error...

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me resolve?

Comment: You forgot to provide `fn_list` to index into

Comment: You said `[i % len(fn_list)]`, but so far that is just a number surrounded by brackets.  To get the function at that position, you need `fn_list[i % len(fn_list)]`.

Comment: You need to put the `print()` call above the other function call.  Then, make the `print()` call `print(name.ljust(max(len(n) for n in name_list), end=" ")`.  In your test functions print `- Run testfunc#` where `#` is the function number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[i % len(fn_list)]()
```

What you were actualy doing is "calling a number" surrounded by brackets (`[number]()`), you need to add the list reference name first.

```
name_list = ["John", "Joe", "Paul" "George", "Mark", "Craig", "Norman"]
# You need to store the functions' references, not their return values
fn_list = [testfunc1, testfunc2, testfunc3] # remove the parentheses


for i, name in enumerate(name_list):
    (fn_list[i % len(fn_list)])() # fn_list[ ... ]
    print(name)
```

Output:

```
This is a test function 1
John
This is a test function 2
Joe
This is a test function 3
PaulGeorge
This is a test function 1
Mark
This is a test function 2
Craig
This is a test function 3
Norman
```